# Facebook Graph API - Retrieving profile picture change time

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is there any way to obtain the time of update of a user/page profile picture in a *datetime* format, using the Facebook Graph API ?

I found the way to obtain the URL etc, but nothing about the update time.

Thanks !

Comment: Not really. With proper permission, you could go through the photos in the Profile Pictures album - but I don’t think you will be able to determine this from there to begin with, because users could use old photos as their current profile pic again. And trying to catch the timeline posts saying “xy updated their profile picture” is likely rather going to be a needle-in-haystack game as well. What would you want with this kind of info in the first place?

Comment: My initial goal was to compute some sort of statistics on the profile management behaviour, among which i'd like to compute the frequency (in days) of profile picture change.

Catching the "x updated its profile picture" seems to be tough indeed...but i'll give it a shot. 

Thanks !